# com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener not working in my activity

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services, google-places-api, google-maps-android-api-2

I would like to retrieve the device position each time the user moves but the onLocationChanged callback does not work. could someone please help me? here is my code of my activity that manages the google map. Please note, I'm using the onLocationChanged from the Google Library com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.firebase.geofire.GeoFire;
import com.firebase.geofire.GeoLocation;
import com.firebase.geofire.LocationCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationResult;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.proper_international.properinternationnal.R;
import com.proper_international.properinternationnal.activity.customer.BookingProviderActivity;
import com.proper_international.properinternationnal.activity.menus.HamburgerMenuProviderActivity;
import com.proper_international.properinternationnal.entities.Nettoyeur;
import com.proper_international.properinternationnal.miscs.UserEnum;
import com.proper_international.properinternationnal.miscs.Utilities;
import com.proper_international.properinternationnal.services.ActionAPIService;
import com.proper_international.properinternationnal.services.FCMNotificationService;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

public class ProviderToCustomerMapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private Button btnAccept, btnDecline;
    FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    String latLong, idReserve, from, login;

    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Location mLastLocation;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    Marker mCurrLocationMarker;


    private LatLng equipierPosition;

    private LocationManager locationManager;

    static int MY_REQUEST_CODE = 225;
    private String provider_info;
    boolean isGPSEnabled, isNetworkEnabled;
    // The minimum distance to change updates in meters
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

    // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (!isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {
            finish();
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_provider_to_customer_maps);
        btnAccept = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAccept);
        btnDecline = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDecline);
        sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(Utilities.MY_PREFERENCE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


        if (getIntent() != null) {
            latLong = getIntent().getStringExtra("latLng");
            idReserve = getIntent().getStringExtra("idReserve");
            from = getIntent().getStringExtra("from");
            login = getIntent().getStringExtra("login");
        }
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);



        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        //getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);


        runOnClick();

        if (!sharedpreferences.getString(Utilities.EXTRA_ROLE, "").equals(UserEnum.Provider.toString())) {
            btnDecline.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            btnAccept.setText("Consulter son profile.");
        }


        btnDecline.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                try {
                    String result = new declinerReservation().execute().get();
                    if (result.equals("true"))
                        Toast.makeText(ProviderToCustomerMapsActivity.this, "Merci!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    finish();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });


        btnAccept.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!sharedpreferences.getString(Utilities.EXTRA_ROLE, "").equals(UserEnum.Customer.toString())) {
                    try {
                        String result = new assignerReservation().execute().get();
                        if (result.equals("true")) {

                            String latLng = mLastLocation.getLatitude() + "," + mLastLocation.getLongitude();

                            String title = "Reservation A.";
                            String body = "Un Eest prêt à vous R.";

                            //Notification PUSH
                            boolean notSend = false;
                            while (notSend == false) {
                                notSend = new FCMNotificationService().execute(from, title, body, latLng, idReserve, sharedpreferences.getString(Utilities.EXTRA_LOGIN, "")).get();
                            }

                            startActivity(new Intent(ProviderToCustomerMapsActivity.this, HamburgerMenuProviderActivity.class));
                            finish();

                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(ProviderToCustomerMapsActivity.this, "Dommage! Un autre Ea décroché cette O.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            finish();
                        }

                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(ProviderToCustomerMapsActivity.this, BookingProviderActivity.class);
                    String[] chaine = idReserve.split(",");
                    intent.putExtra("idReserver", chaine[0]);
                    intent.putExtra("login", chaine[1]);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            }
        });


    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    public void runOnClick() {

        // mGoogleApiClient = this;
        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(ProviderToCustomerMapsActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(ProviderToCustomerMapsActivity.this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
            } else {
                // do request the permission
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, MY_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        }

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(ProviderToCustomerMapsActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(ProviderToCustomerMapsActivity.this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)) {
            } else {
                // do request the permission
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, MY_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        }

         mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Location location) {

                    // Last known location. In some rare situations, it can be null.
                    if (location != null) {
                        // Logique pour gérer l'objet d'emplacement

                        mLastLocation = location;

                    }
                }
         });

        mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnFailureListener(
                new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception ex) {
                        Log.e("getLastLocation", "onFailure: "+ex.getMessage());

                    }
                }
        );

    }

    private boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() {
        int status = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == status) {
            return true;
        } else {
            GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(this, status,  0).show();
            return false;
        }
    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
            } else {
                // do request the permission
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, MY_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        }

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)) {
            } else {
                // do request the permission
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, MY_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        }

        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        if (sharedpreferences.getString(Utilities.EXTRA_ROLE, "").equals(UserEnum.Customer.toString())) {
            btnAccept.setText("Ma liste de R");
            btnAccept.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            //String userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
            String userId = login;
            DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("EDisponible");

            GeoFire geoFire = new GeoFire(ref);
            geoFire.setLocation(userId.replaceAll(".", "_"), new GeoLocation(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude()));

            String[] ll = latLong.split(",");
            double latitude = Double.parseDouble(ll[0]);
            double longitude = Double.parseDouble(ll[1]);


            equipierPosition = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(equipierPosition).title("Position de l'e."));

            geoFire.getLocation(userId.replaceAll(".", "_"), new LocationCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationResult(String key, GeoLocation location) {
                    if (location != null) {
                        System.out.println(String.format("L'emplacement de la clé %s est [%f,%f]", key, location.latitude, location.longitude));
                        equipierPosition = new LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude);
                        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(equipierPosition).title("Position de l'équipier."));
                    } else {
                        Log.d("Pas d'emplacement", String.format("Il n'y a pas d'emplacement pour la clé %s dans GeoFire", key));
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Log.d("Erreur produite", "Une erreur s'est produite lors de l'obtention de l'emplacement GeoFire: " + databaseError);
                }
            });


        } else {

            String userIds = login;
            DatabaseReference refs = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("ClientDisponible");

            String[] ll = latLong.split(",");
            double latitude = Double.parseDouble(ll[0]);
            double longitude = Double.parseDouble(ll[1]);


            GeoFire geoFire = new GeoFire(refs);
            geoFire.setLocation(userIds.replaceAll(".", "_"), new GeoLocation(latitude, longitude));

            equipierPosition = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(equipierPosition).title("Position 0."));


            geoFire.getLocation(userIds.replaceAll(".", "_"), new LocationCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationResult(String key, GeoLocation location) {
                    if (location != null) {
                        System.out.println(String.format("L'emplacement de la clé %s est [%f,%f]", key, location.latitude, location.longitude));
                        equipierPosition = new LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude);
                        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(equipierPosition).title("Position 1."));
                    } else {
                        Log.d("Pas d'emplacement", String.format("Il n'y a pas d'emplacement pour la clé %s dans GeoFire:" + key));
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Log.d("Erreur obtention", databaseError.getMessage());
                }
            });
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == MY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Now user should be able to use camera
            } else {
                // Your app will not have this permission. Turn off all functions
                // that require this permission or it will force close like your
                // original question
            }
        }
    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        //stop location updates when Activity is no longer active
        if (mFusedLocationClient != null) {
            mFusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(mLocationCallback);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback, Looper.myLooper());
       // LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);

    }


    com.google.android.gms.location.LocationCallback mLocationCallback = new com.google.android.gms.location.LocationCallback(){
        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
            for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {
                Log.i("MapsActivity", "Location: " + location.getLatitude() + " " + location.getLongitude());
                mLastLocation = location;
                if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
                    mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
                }

                //Place current location marker
                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                markerOptions.position(latLng);
                markerOptions.title("Position actuelle");
                markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
                mCurrLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

                //move map camera
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 11));
            }
        };

    };

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        runOnClick();
    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mLastLocation = location;
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));

        String userId = login;
        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("EDisponible");
        GeoFire geoFire = new GeoFire(ref);
        geoFire.setLocation(userId.replaceAll(".","_"), new GeoLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        if(user != null){
            String userId = login.replaceAll(".","_");

            DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("EDisponible");
            if (!sharedpreferences.getString(Utilities.EXTRA_ROLE, "").equals(UserEnum.Customer.toString()))
                ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("ClientDisponible");
            GeoFire geoFire = new GeoFire(ref);
            geoFire.removeLocation(userId);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve my problem by adding this line of code in the onConnected method:

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
```

I had not used LocationServices because FusedLocationApi is deprecated.